# Installing xampp 7.3.9-0 in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. Please help me install xampp 7.3.9-0 in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I have tried various ways but none could do it.

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to describe the ways you tried and what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the installer and save it in a folder in your computer. You can either [download](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) it from its website or you can run the following command that downloads it and saves it in your *Home* folder.

```
wget https://downloadsapachefriends.global.ssl.fastly.net/7.3.9/xampp-linux-x64-7.3.9-0-installer.run
```

Change the installer's permissions so that it can be executed (if you saved the installer in a folder other than home, first `cd` into that folder and then run the commands):

```
chmod u+x xampp-linux-x64-7.3.9-0-installer.run
```

Now you can run the installer (requires root privileges):

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.9-0-installer.run
```

Finally, follow the graphical installer's instructions to install the components you need and select `xampp`'s installation directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. it helped.

Comment: Glad I could help!